# Python counting by three

Tags: python

How can I make python begin at a single multiple of three and then count from there? I'm not sure where to go after the elif statement.

Here's my code so far...

```
    count = int(input("How many multiples ot 3 would you like?: "))
    a = int(input("Enter 1 to start at 0 or 2 to start at a multiple of your 
    choice: "))
    if a == 1:
       for x in range(count):
            print(x*3)
    elif a == 2:
```

Comment: Are you aware of `range` with 3 arguments?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range. You can do `range(start, exclusiveEnd, 3)` to define your starting element and step by 3 instead of 1.

Comment: if the user chose 2 at the second prompt, how does the user input the multiple of his choice?

Answer (score 1):

Although you generally just see it being used with the stop parameter alone, the `range()` function actually has start, stop, and step parameters. e.g.

```
>>> for i in range(6, 20, 3): print(i)
6
9
12
15
18
```

So just gather the starting value, and calculate the stop parameter from the start value and the number of multiples desired, and fix the step parameter at three.